# How to combine values having same value in some columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a list of the item that has same value in the transaction column, i tried using for loop but it gives some random addresses.

[CODE AND ERROR SNIPPET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gGfk.png)

For example:

```
lst = [["bread"],["Scandinavian", "Scandinavian"],["Hot chocolate", "Hot chocolate"]]
```

Comment: do you mean: `lst = [["bread"],["Scandinavian", "Scandinavian"],["Hot chocolate", "Jam"]]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict(list)` to keep track of reoccuring `Transaction IDs` in conjuction with `Item` and append the value for it in `refHash`

```
from collections import defaultdict
refHash = defaultdict(list)

for i,id in enumerate(df['Transaction'].values):
    refHash[id] += [df.loc[i,'Item']]

lst = list(refHash.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['Transaction'])['Item'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

Comment: or even easier: `df.groupby(['Transaction'])['Item'].agg(',').tolist()`